# RESTful API design - best practices for passing dates

Tags: api, datetime, rest

What is the best practice for sharing dates in an API?

Is it best to share dates with an SQL-like datetime format - 'YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' with an optional timezone embedded inside of it?

Or is it best to use milliseconds based on UTC?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I prefer to encode times as full [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates, but with the constraint that my code only ever *generates* them in the UTC timezone. If you've got a good date parsing library (e.g., Jodatime for Java) accepting full ISO 8601 is not particularly difficult and they're at least somewhat readable. (Offsets from some epochal instant are nothing like as easy for people to read.)

Comment: I assume we all mean ISO 8601?

Comment: No, I was talking about ISO 5775 on bicycle tires, or perhaps ISO 3632 on saffron… ;-)

Comment: For people looking for an example using this ISO: 2013-10-23T05:02Z (including Date and Time)

Answer (score -1):

It's up to you but, unless you are doing some kind of calendar application, I wouldn't bother with supporting the full ISO format because parsing them while handling the timezone, daylight saving time, etc. can quickly become very complex. Passing them as UTC is almost always good enough, and it's easy for the programmers using your API to convert any date they have to this format.

Comment: -1 for encouraging institutional knowledge. -1 for not explicitly stating timezone.

Comment: -1 It is easy to return UTC zoned datetimes in ISO 8601 format. You do not have to choose one or the other.